# Database Schema : Multiple Admins (CMS)

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database, database-schema

I'm having a hard time to create a schema for my CMS. It is a reservation system for hotels/resorts. I have two users and two connected websites, one for the client and the other for hotel/resort owners (CMS). The owners should create his own account and using that account he can add more than one hotels/resorts, the problem is the owner should be able to add an admin or another user that can access his account so that in case he would not be able to update his reservations he can ask his assistant to update the it. My current schema is like this

**Users**

- id
- name
- bday
- age
- and other personal details

then..

**Hotels**

- id
- user_id
- name
- rooms
- and other details

When the owner logged in to his account Im getting all his hotels using this query:

`SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE user_id = <owner id>`

Im thinking of just adding another column like (user_id_2) and (user_id_3) in hotels table. but i don't think that's the right way because that would limit the number of admins. What do you guys think?

Comment: You should create a new table called `users_hotels` that contains `id, user_id, hotel_id`. Then you have that table as a reference on which user belongs to which hotel. That way, a hotel can have an unlimited amount of users without you needing to change your DB. To get all the hotels for a user, use: `SELECT * FROM hotels INNER JOIN users_hotels ON users_hotels.hotel_id = hotels.id WHERE users_hotels.user_id = :user_id`. Read more about [Database Normalization](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/)

Comment: I haven't thought of that. Thank you!!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson how about if one hotel has many users (admins) that can access? or when there is many hotels handled by one user?

Comment: If you have that intermediate table, you'll get a "many-to-many" relationship. One user can have many hotels and one hotel can have many users. You simply add a new row in that table. One per hotel and user combo.